# how to programmatically add a language in keyboards and languages in control panel using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

i needed to know how one can add a language in keyboards and languages option in control panel programmatically using c++...I am able to change locale progragrammatically through LOADKEYBOARDLAYOUT in task bar but if the IME is not present in keyboards and languages i am unable to enter the characters.

I have to manually add the IME through control panel...but i need to do it programmatically...Currently i am facing issues of entering chinese characters....

If IME is added manually through Control Panel i am able to enter chinese characters...but i need to do it programmatically..

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated....(prefarabbly in c++)

Currently i am using Windows 7 Operating System

Comment: I give you a small hint, search for LoadKeyboardLayout -> ActivateKeyboardLayout -> UnloadKeyboardLayout on msdn

Comment: thanks Kirilodius for replying..But it doesnt help.I have tried LoadKeyboardLayout locale in task bar is changing..for entering characters Pinyin keyboard has to be activated manually in control panel..i have to do it programmatically

Comment: OK, 

`**ActivateKeyboardLayout** function
Sets the input locale identifier (formerly called the keyboard layout handle) for the calling thread or the current process. The input locale identifier specifies a locale as well as the physical layout of the keyboard.`

So please clarify are you trying to set keyboard layout for system wide or only for your application?

Comment: Its at application level.When i change the language back to english,it should come back to default i.e English US